# Why is Swift 2.0 app throwing EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when I use for-in loop?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I'm trying to solve the Euler Problem #2 using Swift 2.0 which is to find the sume of all the even numbers in a fibonacci sequence under 4 million. When I try to iterate to 4 million Xcode is throwing an error "Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code = EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

```
var num1 = 0
var num2 = 1
var sum = 0
var evenSum = 0
var max = 4000000

for i in (1...max){
    print(i)
    sum = num1 + num2 //ERROR HERE!
    num1 = num2
    num2 = sum
    if((sum % 2) == 0){
        print(sum)
        evenSum += sum
    }
}
print("\(evenSum)",terminator:"")
```

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY6C8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is an integer overflow. The sum is getting too large. Swift *intentionally* crashes your program when that happens, unlike other languages where you get a garbage result.

You can get *a bit* further by using Int64 for the type of the variables, but not much.

BTW. Re-read the Euler Problem statement again carefully. Your program is not calculating what the Euler Problem #2 is asking for.

Comment: BTW: great hint at the end!